# How to remove unwanted values from arrayed input?

Tags: php, laravel

I just wanted to ask how can we avoid this kind of output from arrayed input. Every time I update it, these symbols ["\"[ keeps on multiplying. I'll show you the problem and the code below. 
Thank you your future answers.

[image]
[image]

**Route::resource('setups','SetupController');**

```
public function index()
    {
       $data = DB::table('setups')->first();
        if (!empty($data)) {        
            $socials = explode(',',$data -> social);
        }else{
            $socials = [];
        }
        return view ('adminpanel.setup.index',['data' => $data,'socials' => $socials]);
    }
```

**index.blade.php**

```
<form action="{{ route('setups.edit',$data->id) }}">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12" id="socialGroup">
    @foreach($socials as $social)
    <div class="form-group socialField">
    <label class="bmd-label-floating">Social Links</label>
      <input type="text" name="social[]" value="{{$social}}" class="form-control" disabled>
      <a href="#" class="addField"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></a>
    </div>
    @endforeach
    <div class="alert alert-danger" id="socialError">
    <p><strong>Sorry! </strong>You've reached the max number for social links form.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<form>
```

.

```
public function edit($id)
    {
        $data = DB::table('setups')->first();
        $setup = DB::table('setups')->where('id', $id)->first();
        if (!empty($data)) {        
            $socials = explode(',',$data -> social);
        }else{
            $socials = [];
        }

        if($setup){
        return view ('adminpanel.setup.edit',['data' => $data,'socials' => $socials]);
        }else{
            return redirect('setups');
        }
    }
```

.

**edit.blade.php**

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('setups.update', $data->id) }}">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12" id="socialGroup">
    @foreach($socials as $social)
    <div class="form-group socialField">
    <label class="bmd-label-floating">Social Links</label>
      <input type="text" name="social[]" value="{{ $social }}" class="form-control">
      <a href="#" class="addField"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></a>
    </div>
    @endforeach
    <div class="alert alert-danger" id="socialError">
    <p><strong>Sorry! </strong>You've reached the max number for social links form.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<form>
```

.

```
public function update(Request $request, Setup $setup)
{
    $data = Input::except('_token', 'submit', '_method');
    $tbl = decrypt($data['tbl']);
    unset ($data['tbl']);

    $data['updated_at'] = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    DB::table($tbl)->where(key($data), reset($data))->update($data);

    session::flash('message','Setup updated successfully!!!');
    return redirect()->route('setups.index');
}
```

> **Solved!** I just added this code in my SetupController@update to illuminate those unwanted divider or separator(whatever) before
>   sending to database.

```
if (Input::has('social')) {
            $data['social'] = implode(',',$data['social']);
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Looks like the data was just escaped twice. Maybe you have some other code that is escaping the data (or maybe automatic escaping in your PHP config) before sending the query.

Comment: laravel escaped data by default. It was not giving any error,whenever you retrieve data from database to throw in your blade view.Database data escaping is good practice.But as you showed your data,there is some unwanted data.Before you attempt to post your data,you may trim your data for unwanted white space from start & end of a string.

Comment: And there is also some empty string value,whose are also unwanted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved! I just added this code in my SetupController@update

```
if (Input::has('social')) {
            $data['social'] = implode(',',$data['social']);
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

> laravel escaped data by default. It was not giving any error,whenever
>   you retrieve data from database to throw in your blade view.Database
>   data escaping is good practice.

As you showed your data,there is some unwanted data.Before you attempt to save your data,you may `trim($yourString)` to remove unwanted white-space from start & end of a string.

And You must not let **blank** or **empty** string to view in your blade. So, you might use `blank($var)` to check whether it is blank or not?

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('setups.update', $data->id) }}">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12" id="socialGroup">
    @foreach($socials as $social)
      @if(!blank($social))
       <div class="form-group socialField">
         <label class="bmd-label-floating">Social Links</label>
         <input type="text" name="social[]" value="{{ $social }}" class="form-control">
         <a href="#" class="addField"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></a>
       </div>
      @endif
    @endforeach
    <div class="alert alert-danger" id="socialError">
     <p><strong>Sorry! </strong>You've reached the max number for social links form.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I did try the value="{{ trim($social) }}" but still has this ["facebook","messenger","youtube"]

Comment: I think this is okay.if it's not okay;Please,let me know how it supposed to!!

Comment: I want to store it this way facebook, messenger, youtube. So if I display the data there's no [""].